# Data-binding to KVP of Object,Object not allowing properties to be used or updated in real time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have Operation class and Result class that I use to build a list, I use xaml to bind to the properties and a converter to return some content based on certain properties, Most of this works....

To make it easy I will post the xaml then note what works and what I need help with.

```
<UserControl x:Class="OperationListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"   
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
         xmlns:inf="clr-namespace:***;assembly=***"
         xmlns:c="clr-namespace:****.***"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Control.Resources>
    <c:LanguageTextConverter x:Key="langConverter" />
    <c:ResultViewConverter x:Key="statusConverter" />
    <c:OpDetailViewConverter x:Key="opConverter" />
</Control.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadGridView Name="OperationGrid"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         RowHeight="75"
                         SelectionMode="Single"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOperation, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                         ShowGroupPanel="False"
                         RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" >
        <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Template="{Binding Converter={StaticResource opConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Key.operationName, Converter={StaticResource langConverter}}"
                                        Width="2*"
                                        IsGroupable="False" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Result"
                                        Width="1*"
                                        MaxWidth="75"> 
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentControl Template="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource statusConverter}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns> 
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

everything up to the final binding works, and even the final binding works to a point...

```
<ContentControl Template="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource statusConverter}}"/>
```

this works, when binding to Value the converter fires on load and loads the appropriate xaml.

However no additional changes update this value...

In the code behind at some point the Value.status is updated , the setter on the status property fires an propertyChanged. but nothing is caught on the front end.

```
public OverallStatus status
    {
        get { return this.Status; }
        set { this.Status = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "status"); }
    }
```

What is the property syntax to bind to a Value.Property (currently doesn't work at all) AND have it recognize the propertyChanged setter 3 levels down from the view.

Comment: Whats your bounded record (dataitem), and type of Value ? Type of status can be seen as OverllStatus. Ie; in the hierarchy Item>Value>status, what are the types of Item and Value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample showing nested properties. When I change a property value at button click, it is reflected in the grid. More can be read here : 
[Property path syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742451(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="524.627" Width="862.313">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.Status.Name}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Status"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,38,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>


using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {  
            InitializeComponent();

            Dgrd.ItemsSource = DataStore.Operations;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataStore.Operations[0].Value.Status.Name = "N/A"; // change first item
        }
    }

    public class DataStore
    {
        //static List<Operation> _operations;
        public static List<Operation> Operations;

        static DataStore()
        {
            Operations =
                new List<Operation>() { 
                    new Operation(){ Value = new RecordInner(){ Status = new OverallStatus (){ Name="Pending"}}},
                    new Operation(){ Value = new RecordInner(){ Status = new OverallStatus (){ Name="Started"}}},
                    new Operation(){ Value = new RecordInner(){ Status = new OverallStatus (){ Name="Completed"}}}
                };
        }

    }

    public class Operation
    {
        RecordInner _value;
        public RecordInner Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }
    }

    public class RecordInner
    { 
        OverallStatus _status;
        public OverallStatus Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set { _status = value; }
        }
    }

    public class OverallStatus:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _name;
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("name"); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}
```